# MySQLi multi_query results for later use

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using MySQLi multi_query to work with several select statemets at a time.
What i would like to know is how to handle results, so i will be able to use them later in code.

**Example:**

```
<?php

//connection stuff

$query = "SELECT name, surname FROM database1;";
$query.= "SELECT car, year, type FROM database2 WHERE carID='1';";
$query.= "SELECT product, price FROM database3;";

if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {

if($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {

while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {

-->   what to do here?

}

}

}

?>

<html>

<div id='persona'>
<?php
foreach() {
--> print name + surname
}
?>
</div>

<div id='cars'>
<?php
foreach() {
--> print car + year + type
}
?>
</div>

<div id='product'>
<?php
foreach() {
--> print product + price
}
?>
</div>

</html>
```

One more thing, **prepared statements** are not possible when using multiple_query, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really is no benefit in putting unrelated queries together in one multi query call. In fact, the risk of getting hit by a SQL injection is way bigger! The regular query function does only allow one query per call, so it is impossible to inject something into a SELECT statement, ending it prematurely and then add a DELETE.

With multi_query, this is possible.

Additionally, you have to fetch and end each query, and then it's gone. You you cannot change between the query results at will, they have to be fetched in exactly the order they were issued.

The better way is to just execute independent simple queries. This would allow you to use prepared statements as well, and as long as you are not getting HUGE amounts of data back, it will probably use the same amount of memory and not annoy anyone.